# Can't use an element of a list as an argument in an object's constructor

Tags: java, arrays, object, for-loop, constructor

```
    final int NUM_OF_SERVERS = 2;

    List<Database> databases = new ArrayList<Database>();

    for (int i = 1; i < NUM_OF_SERVERS; i++){

        Database database = new Database("server" + i + ".txt");
        databases.add(database);

    }

    List<Server> servers = new ArrayList<Server>();

    for (int i = 1; i < NUM_OF_SERVERS; i++){

        **Server server = new Server(databases[i-1]);** //the error is here
    }
```

I have a list of databases and I want to make a list of Servers using elements of a list of databases as arguments for a constructor but it throws this error: "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List" when mouseovering the highlighted line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `databases` is a `List<Database>` - not a `Database[]`. Therefore the expression `databases[i-1]` is invalid. This has nothing to do with the fact that you're calling a constructor - that's just not how you access an element in a list. You want `databases.get(i - 1)`

```
for (int i = 1; i < NUM_OF_SERVERS; i++) {
    Server server = new Server(databases.get(i-1));
    // Presumably do something with server here
}
```

It seems to me that you've got an off-by-one error though - you're only going to end up with `NUM_OF_SERVERS - 1` servers. I suspect you would be better off with:

```
final int NUM_OF_SERVERS = 2;

List<Database> databases = new ArrayList<Database>();

// Note the change to starting index
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_SERVERS; i++) {
    Database database = new Database("server" + i + ".txt");
    databases.add(database);
}

List<Server> servers = new ArrayList<Server>();
// Note the change to starting index *and* the use of i rather than i - 1 
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_SERVERS; i++) {
    Server server = new Server(databases.get(i));
    // Use server here
}
```

Or even better, use an enhanced for loop for the second loop:

```
for (Database database : databases) {
    Server server = new Server(database);
    // Use server here
}
```